# webscraper got #AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to download all those hot custom bikes' images from this website.
[bikeexif.com](https://www.bikeexif.com/)

I'm trying to make folders by every article's name.
But problem is, some of those article name has special character ':' which makes me wonder it caused problem or not.
So I tried replace it first as this '-' to see more clearly.

problem example # RED ZED: AC SANCTUARY’S 152 HP Z1000 RACER

After I run my code, I got

> line 20, in 
> new_name = album_name.replace(':', '-')
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

I still don't understand what to do. (I'm a newbie)

Anyone can help?

Thanks

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import parsel
import os
import time

for page in range(1, 309):
    print(f'======= Scraping data from page {page} =======')

    url = f'https://www.bikeexif.com/page/{page}'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8'
    html_data = response.text
    selector = parsel.Selector(html_data)

    image_album_list = selector.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div')
    for li in image_album_list:
        album_name = li.xpath('.//div/div/@h2').get()
        new_name = album_name.replace(':', '-')
        album_url = li.xpath('.//div/div/a/@href').get()
        print(album_name, album_url)

        if not os.path.exists('img\\' + new_name):
            os.mkdir('img\\' + new_name)

        response_image = requests.get(url=album_url, headers=headers).text
        selector_image = parsel.Selector(response_image)

        images_url_a = selector_image.xpath('//div[@class="image-container"]/img/@data-src').getall()
        # images_url_b = selector_image.xpath('//div[@class="image-container"]/img/@src').getall()
        for album_url in images_url_a:
            image_data = requests.get(url=album_url, headers=headers).content
            time.sleep(1)

            file_name = album_url.split('/')[-1]
            with open(f'img\\{new_name}\\' + file_name, mode='wb') as f:
                f.write(image_data)
                print(file_name)
```

Comment: `li.xpath('.//div/div/a/@href').get()` returned `None`. Presumably this means that there was no matching element. You need to handle this case differently than if an element `album_name` was returned.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit on @mkrieger1's comment, what you *should* do depends on what you want to happen, and whether `album_name=None` is allowed for your data. Some examples:
If no-album-name is allowed, and you just want to print the results, you can simply replace that one `album_name.replace()` call with something like

```
if album_name is not None:
    new_name = album_name.replace(':', '-')
```

If you're doing other processing you haven't talked about here, and having `album_name is None` gives a specific alternate path you should take to process otherwise "normal" data, you can follow the `if album_name is not None:` block above with an `else:` that assumes `album_name is None`.

If you just want to skip getting the `album_url` (and anything else you normally do) in response to `album_name is None`, put all the stuff you want to skip inside the above `if album_name is not None:` conditional and the code will silently ignore  those records.

If `album_name is None` is definitely an error / unexpected condition, read up on [try/except blocks](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/) and figure out what sorts of error handling you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'm still working on it.